# create new activity from message AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I want to click on some part of text that showed by AlertDialog and to start a new activity.
I just dont know if it possible.
Here my example of my code

```
case R.id.about:
        final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
        .setMessage(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.infoAuthor)+" <br> <a href=\"https://www.youtube.com">click here for help</a>"))
        .create();
        d.show();
        // Make the textview clickable. Must be called after show()   
        ((TextView)d.findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly setting the message of the AlertDialog, create a TextView and set the HTML and LinkMovementMethod on it. Then call [`AlertDialog.Builder#setView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28android.view.View%29) with this TextView. Example using your code:

```
case R.id.about:
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.infoAuthor)+" <br> <a href=\"https://www.youtube.com">click here for help</a>");
        tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
        .setView(tv);
        .create();
        d.show(getFragmentManager, "tag");
```